# Showing the tubular neighbourhood theorem, special case

Tags: differential-geometry

I have $N$ a compact manifold which can be embedded into a 1 dimension higher manifold $M$ (both manifolds without boundary)  suppose you have a normal bundle of $N$ (i.e. a section of the tangent bundle of $M$ only defined on $N$ which is not included in the tangent space of $N$). I'm trying to show that there is a neighbourhood of $N$ diffeomorphic to $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times N$ for some $\varepsilon$.

I managed to extend the tangent bundle of the inclusion of $N$ into an open set around $N$ and then I used the existence of integral curves to establish a map between $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times N$ to $M$ at each point. But how do I glue these together? i.e. can't my solutions to integral curves have smaller and smaller domains where they are defined?

Comment: You're assuming that $\dim M = \dim N + 1$?

Comment: Yes, would it not work for lower dimensions of N though?

Comment: Actuallly, I take it back its quite clear geometrically it would not work for lower dimensions of N.

Comment: No, but then there's a neighborhood that's diffeomorphic to a neighborhood of the zero-section of the normal bundle of $N$ in $M$. This is called the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem.